# In what order does Python find syntax errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, syntax, syntax-error

Working on creating syntax debugging exercise for students. We have the following example.

```
def five():
    print('five')
return 5

def hello();
   print('hello')
```

However when running the file the syntax error is

```
def hello();
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've looked all over but can not figure out why the compiler [sic] doesn't complain about the return keyword outside of the function, but instead first finds the semicolon error under it.

In what order does Python check the file syntax? Is this part of the specification or is it implemenation defined?

Answer (score 14):

There are (at least) two phases involved: first, the token stream is parsed to produce a parse tree according to the [grammar rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html). A `return` statement is part of the `flow_stmt` rule, which itself is not restricted to being used inside a `def` statement. It is not a *parse* error to have a bare `return` statement. Some selected, relevant rules from the grammar:

```
single_input: NEWLINE | simple_stmt | compound_stmt NEWLINE
file_input: (NEWLINE | stmt)* ENDMARKER
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt

simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
         import_stmt | global_stmt | nonlocal_stmt | assert_stmt)
flow_stmt: break_stmt | continue_stmt | return_stmt | raise_stmt | yield_stmt
return_stmt: 'return' [testlist_star_expr]
```

The next phase involves turning the parse tree into a syntax tree. At this point, finding a `return` statement outside of a `def` statement would produce a syntax error.

---

A `;`, on the other hand, is *not* part of the definition of `funcdef`, so a `;` in place of the expected `:` would immediately trigger an error while building the parse tree.

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ['->' test] ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] func_body_suite
```

While it may be *possible* to report the bare `return` statement earlier, it clearly does not *need* to happen, so I would say this is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes total sense.